# Start Button and MsSettings do not work

Tags: windows, virus

I have a problem with my laptop. If I click the Windows Button, nothing happend and if I try to press WINDOWS + I nothing happend. I try use WINDOWS + R to open ms-settings: and it gives me this error: file system error (-805043884). I try to run in CMD as Admin the DISM/online/cleanup-image/CheckHealth command and it gives me the 87 error. I try also try to run SFC /Scannow and it says that is impossible to run the services.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows setup seems to be in a very bad shape.

If this wasn't caused by anything you did, the computer might
be infected, so run a few deep antivirus scans to check this
possibility. If any infection is found, see the article
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

To correct the problem and bring Windows back to a coherent state
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation is equivalent to a major Windows upgrade, so should be
treated the same way (take backups).

Comment: I am running a anti-virus scans

Comment: A solution is to reinstall Windows?

Comment: Yes, that's the ultimate solution, but may cause its own problems if a needed driver is missing from the installation media. An intermediate solution would be to [Refresh Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4090-refresh-windows-10-a.html).